# Python Threading difficulty

Tags: python, multithreading

*I am working on a small program that will display a loading message while it checks to see if you have functioning internet by pinging google. But whenever I try to run it, it just stays on the little loading gizmo. Any ideas?*

### Edit

So I fixed my problem of the loading gizmo not stopping, but now I have another problem. This source is a snippet of a larger program, and when the program has determined that your internet is functional, the loading gizmo stops. It's than supposed to ping some websites, but instead it just waits for a second and then exits. Does anyone know what's up with that?

```
import urllib2, time, threading
def ping():
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
    network = 1
except IOError:
    network = 0

def network_waiting():
    while network == '?':
        print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... \ ",
        time.sleep(.07)
        print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... |",
        time.sleep(.07)
        print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... /",
        time.sleep(.07)
        print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... -",
        time.sleep(.07)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target = ping) 
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = network_waiting)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Comment: How do you implement a thread? What you show is not a correct way to implement a thread.

Comment: You need to declare `network` as a global variable.

Comment: thank you! this solved my initial problem of the loading gizmo not working, but now the the rest of the program won't run. see my post above ^

Comment: @KJWing: please, choose your question and stick with it. If you've noticed a new issue and it *completely changes the original question* then [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of updating your current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some confusion about how to actually define and start a thread.  You do not create a thread by simply using "thread" in the variable's name.  One way that you could do this instead is to create a thread object that knows to call your ping and network_waiting methods.  Here's an example of doing so:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target = ping)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = network_waiting)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

If you're interested in additional tutorials, check out [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

---

Edit: Now that you've fixed the call into threads, see @vanza's comment above.  Here's how to declare `network` as a global variable (discussion following):

```
import urllib2, time, threading
network = '?'
def ping():
  global network
  try:
      urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
      network = 1
  except IOError:
      network = 0

def network_waiting():
  global network
  while network == '?':
      print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... \ ",
      time.sleep(.07)
      print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... |",
      time.sleep(.07)
      print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... /",
      time.sleep(.07)
      print "\r[*] Checking network availability.... -",
      time.sleep(.07)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target = ping) 
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = network_waiting)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Essentially, without using the `global` keyword, Python thinks that in your `ping` method, you are creating a local variable named `network` and writing to it, rather than overwriting the `network` variable in the global scope.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I tried your example, and it didn't work. edited post

Comment: @KJWing, I've edited the post above to address your additional question.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, this has created another problem. see above.

Comment: +1: for the patience. In general, `global` should be avoided. Though it is probably fine for the small example.

Answer (score 0):

`print` statement prints to stdout that is buffered by default. You could use stderr to report progress. Also one thread is enough here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
import sys
import threading
import time
import urllib2

def is_internet_up():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com", timeout=30).close()
    except EnvironmentError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def show_spinner(msg):
    def spin():
        for c in itertools.cycle(r"\|/-"):
            if stopped.is_set():
                break
            sys.stderr.write("\r%s %s" % (msg, c))
            time.sleep(0.07)

    stopped = threading.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=spin)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    return stopped.set

stop_spinner = show_spinner("[*] Checking network availability....")
isup = is_internet_up()
stop_spinner()
print("\rInternet is " + ("up" if isup else "down"))
```

Comment: thank totally worked, thank you a ton! and also, thanks for your input above about my new problem. I'll keep that in mind the next time I ask a question.